# How many Times I can Bid on Same domain name and Is There any way to increase bidding amount during auction

Tags: blockchain, ens

Is it Possible to increase my bidding during ENS auction period ?How can see highest bidding before reveling period.
How many times i can bid for the same doamin in 3 days aution period